# Upgrading attr_accessible from Rails 3 to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

I'm trying to systematically upgrade from rails 3 to rails 4 and all of my 25 models are based on attr_accessor! So before getting into that can anyone provide me a simple example on how to do this. I've read the documentation and other topics but it's not clear on how to do it since this is my first upgrade Rodeo.

```
class Settings < ActiveRecord::Base
  image_accessor :favicon
  attr_accessible :company_name, :show_hot_jobs, :show_students, :subheading, :show_testimonials, :show_on_boarding, :max_concurrent_applications
  attr_accessible :image_uid, :max_concurrent_application_groups
  attr_accessible :primary_color, :white_color, :gray_color, :opacity, :locale, :lang_nl, :lang_fr, :lang_de, :lang_en, :privacy_page
  attr_accessible :show_evp, :show_contact_person, :show_jobs_for_you
  attr_accessible :favicon, :favicon_uid, :remove_favicon, :retained_favicon
  attr_accessible :home_url, :show_correspondence, :show_appointment
  attr_accessible :sliderone_uid, :slidertwo_uid, :sliderthree_uid, :sliderfour_uid, :sliderfive_uid
  attr_accessible :sliderone_link, :slidertwo_link, :sliderthree_link, :sliderfour_link, :sliderfive_link
  attr_accessible :sliderone_testoverview,  :slidertwo_testoverview, :sliderthree_testoverview, :sliderfour_testoverview, :sliderfive_testoverview
  attr_accessible :sliderone_page,  :slidertwo_page, :sliderthree_page, :sliderfour_page, :sliderfive_page

  validate :any_lang_present?
  validates :max_concurrent_applications, :numericality => { :greater_than_equal_to => 1 }
  validates :max_concurrent_application_groups, :numericality => { :greater_than_equal_to => 1 }

  # Fav Icon Validation
  validates_property :ext, of: :favicon, :in => ['ico', 'png', 'gif']

  has_paper_trail

  has_many :setting_translations, :foreign_key => :setting_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :setting_translations, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank
  attr_accessible :setting_translations_attributes, :allow_destroy => true

  translates :subheading, :company_name, :image_uid, :home_url, :sliderone_uid, :slidertwo_uid, :sliderthree_uid, :sliderfour_uid, :sliderfive_uid
  translates :sliderone_link, :slidertwo_link, :sliderthree_link, :sliderfour_link, :sliderfive_link
  translates :sliderone_testoverview,  :slidertwo_testoverview, :sliderthree_testoverview, :sliderfour_testoverview, :sliderfive_testoverview
  translates :sliderone_page,  :slidertwo_page, :sliderthree_page, :sliderfour_page, :sliderfive_page
```

Comment: @MarekLipka how to convert the above to rails 4.

Comment: `attr_accessor` != `attr_accessible`. `attr_accessor` is a Ruby method that is not affected by upgrading Rails.

Comment: @sevenseacat changed it to attr_accessible in the title sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessible` can be converted like so:

#### From

```
class Settings
  attr_accessible :home_url
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :setting_translations
end

class SettingTranslation
  attr_accessible :etc
end
```

#### To

```
class SettingsController

  def create
    @settings = Settings.new(settings_params)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def settings_params
    params.require(:settings).permit(
      :home_url,
      :setting_translations_attributes => [:id, :_destroy, :etc]
    )
  end
end
```

Note, you have to include `:_destroy` if you want to allow destroy on that model (`:allow_destroy => true`), and you have to include all attributes that should be accessible from any nested attributes. Though you remove `attr_accessible` when you've permitted, you do *not* remove `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I'm currently in the middle of another development. I will pick this up in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove attr_accessible from model. and add permit params according to need in controller.
like below :

```
class SupportTicketsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @support_ticket = SupportTicket.create(house_params)
    ......
  end

  private

  def house_params
    params.require(:support_ticket).permit(:subject, :message, ....)
  end

end
```

and if you don't want to make this much changes then add "protected_attributes" gem https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes in your gemfile And everything would work as before.